# Can't get CreateDDSTextureFromFile to work

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, hresult, dds-format

So, I've been trying to figure out my problem for a few hours now, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm a noob when it comes to DirectX programming, so I've been following some tutorials, and right now, I'm trying to create a obj loader.
http://www.braynzarsoft.net/index.php?p=D3D11OBJMODEL

However, I can't get my texture to work.

This is how I try to load the DDS-texture:

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* tempMeshSRV = nullptr;
hr = CreateDDSTextureFromFile(gDevice, L"boxTexture.dds", NULL, &tempMeshSRV);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
 {
 textureNameArray.push_back(L"boxTexture.dds");
 material[matCount - 1].texArrayIndex = meshSRV.size();
 meshSRV.push_back(tempMeshSRV);
 material[matCount - 1].hasTexture = true;
 }
```

However, my HRESULT will never Succeed, but it doesn't crash either. If I hoover over the hr, it just says "HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED) I also tried to remove the if statement, but that will just turn my box black.
Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? =/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you're using the DirectXTex library so you should have the actual source code.  If you try stepping into the function in a debugger, where does it fail?

Comment: I'm using the DirectX Toolkit. I stepped into it, but eh.. I'm not sure exactly where it goes to the error..

Comment: Note that you can convert Wavefront OBJ models to VBO, CMO, or SDKMESH using *meshconvert* from [DirectXMesh](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324981) and then load those with [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) using ``Model``. Look [here](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Rendering%20a%20model) for a walk-through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely problem is that your "boxTexture.dds" is a 24 bit-per-pixel format file. In Direct3D 9, this was `D3DFMT_R8G8B8` and was reasonably common. However, there is [no DXGI equivalent format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205073.aspx#mapping_texture_formats) for 24 bits-per-pixel and it therefore requires format conversion to work.

The DDSTextureLoader module in [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) is designed to be a minimum-overhead function, and therefore does *no runtime conversions at all*. If the data directly maps to a DXGI format, it loads. If it doesn't, it fails with `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED)`.

There are two different solutions depending on your usage scenario.

1. The ideal solution is to convert 'boxTexture.dds' to a supported format. You can do this with the *texconv* command-line tool provided with [DirectXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926). This is by far the best option so that the potentially expensive conversion operation is done once and not very single time your application runs and loads the data.
2. If you don't actually control the source of the dds files you are trying load (i.e. they are arbitrary files provided by a user or you are doing some kind of content tool that has to support legacy formats), then you should make use of the [DirectXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926) 'full-fat' `LoadFromDDSFile` function which has extensive conversion code for handling legacy DDS file formats.

Note this situation can happen for a number of legacy format DDS files as list in the [CodePlex wiki documentation](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DDSTextureLoader)

- D3DFMT_R8G8B8 (24bpp RGB) - Use a 32bpp format
- D3DFMT_X8B8G8R8 (32bpp RGBX) - Use BGRX, BGRA, or RGBA
- D3DFMT_A2R10G10B10 (BGRA 10:10:10:2) - Use RGBA 10:10:10:2
- D3DFMT_X1R5G5B5 (BGR 5:5:5) - Use BGRA 5:5:5:1 or BGR 5:6:5
- D3DFMT_A8R3G3B2, D3DFMT_R3G3B2 (BGR 3:3:2) - Expand to a supported format
- D3DFMT_P8, D3DFMT_A8P8 (8-bit palette) - Expand to a supported format
- D3DFMT_A4L4 (Luminance 4:4) - Expand to a supported format
- D3DFMT_UYVY (YUV 4:2:2 16bpp) - Swizzle to YUY2

See also [Direct3D 11 Textures and Block Compression](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/04/direct3d-11-textures-and-block-compression.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code for CreateTextureFromDDS (which is called by CreateDDSTextureFromFile to do the main data processing) - http://directxtk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Src/DDSTextureLoader.cpp - you will see that there are a lot of reasons you could be getting "HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED)".

It's not likely a problem with opening or reading the file since that would return a different error code. So most likely its an unsupported DXGI_FORMAT, a malformed cubemap, an invalid mipmap count, or invalid image dimensions (i.e. larger than the limits found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff819065(v=vs.85).aspx ).

Comment: Aye, it seems like it doesn't like my DXGI_FORMAT:

    DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
    format = GetDXGIFormat( header->ddspf );
It set the format to unknown. Why is that?

Comment: Either the file is corrupt, not actually a DDS file, or in some odd/old format. Without access to the image file that is giving you trouble that's the best I can do. Try viewing the image in a program that will let you view DDSs and see if it works there. DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN means just that: the format of the image data is unknown (and as such nothing useful can be done with it beyond saving the data to some other file). If that's the only thing that is wrong, you can try setting it to each of the formats and viewing the result (if any) until it looks right. Then you'd know the format.